# NSFetchedResultsController fault: attempt to delete item from section 0 which only contains 1 items before the update with userInfo (null)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an application which uses Core Data. In it there are posts, for each post there are many tags. For each tag there are many posts.

I have a home view controller which displays a collection view of all tags. The data source for this collectionView is powered by a NSFetchedResultsController

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var latestTagsCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Tag>!
    var blockOperations: [BlockOperation] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.latestTagsCollectionView.dataSource = self
        self.latestTagsCollectionView.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        //1
        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }
        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        //2
        let fetchRequest =
            NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Tag")
        //3
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = []

        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil) as? NSFetchedResultsController<Tag>
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    func configure(cell: UICollectionViewCell, for indexPath: IndexPath) {

        guard let cell = cell as? TagCollectionViewCell else {
            return
        }
        print(indexPath,"indexPath")
        let tag = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        guard let timeAgo = tag.mostRecentUpdate as Date? else { return }
        cell.timeAgo.text = dateFormatter.string(from: timeAgo)
        if let imageData = tag.mostRecentThumbnail {
            cell.thumbnail.image = UIImage(data:imageData as Data,scale:1.0)
        } else {
            cell.thumbnail.image = nil
        }
        cell.tagName.text = tag.name
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    }

    //CollectionView Stuff
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let sectionData = fetchedResultsController.sections?[section] else {
            return 0
        }
        return sectionData.numberOfObjects
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = latestTagsCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "latestTagCell", for: indexPath) as! TagCollectionViewCell
        configure(cell: cell, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>,
                             didChange anObject: Any,
                             at indexPath: IndexPath?,
                             for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
                             newIndexPath: IndexPath?){
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            print("Insert Object: \(String(describing: newIndexPath))")
            blockOperations.append(
                BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                    if let this = self {
                        this.latestTagsCollectionView!.insertItems(at: [newIndexPath!])
                    }
                })
            )
        case .update:
            blockOperations.append(
                BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                    if let this = self {
                        this.latestTagsCollectionView!.reloadItems(at: [newIndexPath!])
                    }
                })
            )
        case .move:
            blockOperations.append(
                BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                    if let this = self {
                        this.latestTagsCollectionView!.moveItem(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
                    }
                })
            )
        case .delete:
            print("deleted record")
            blockOperations.append(
                BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                    if let this = self {
                        this.latestTagsCollectionView!.deleteItems(at: [newIndexPath!])
                    }
                })
            )
        default: break
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        latestTagsCollectionView!.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
            for operation: BlockOperation in self.blockOperations {
                operation.start()
            }
        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            self.blockOperations.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        })
    }

    deinit {
        // Cancel all block operations when VC deallocates
        for operation: BlockOperation in blockOperations {
            operation.cancel()
        }
        blockOperations.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
    }
```

On a different view controller I allow users to add posts. For each post the user can add a number of different tags. Here is the method called when the post is saved:

```
func save(){
    guard let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    var postTags:[Tag] = []

    if let tokens = tagsView.tokens() {
        for token in tokens {
            let tagFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Tag> = Tag.fetchRequest()
            tagFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", token.title)
            do {
                let res = try managedContext.fetch(tagFetchRequest)
                var tag: Tag!
                if res.count > 0 {
                    tag = res.first
                } else {
                    tag = Tag(context: managedContext)
                    tag.name = token.title
                    tag.mostRecentUpdate = NSDate()
                    tag.mostRecentThumbnail = UIImage(named: "Plus")!.pngData() as! NSData
                }
                postTags.append(tag)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                return
            }
        }
    }
    let post = Post(context: managedContext)
    for tag in postTags {
        tag.addToPosts(post)
        post.addToTags(tag)
    }
    post.mediaURI = URL(string: "https://via.placeholder.com/150")
    post.notes = "some notes..."
    post.timeStamp = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 8, to: Date()) as! NSDate
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

As you can see each tag is either recognized in the database or created if it doesn't exist. For this bug, I am starting with no data in the database. First I create a post with the tag "one". Then I go back to the Home View Controller's view. I see a new tag called "One" is created.

```
Insert Object: Optional([0, 0])
```

gets printed as the .insert case is applied to the NSFetchedResultsController's callback method.

I then add a post with two tags: "One", "Two".

```
Insert Object: Optional([0, 0])
2018-12-05 12:51:16.947569-0800 SweatNetOffline[71327:19904799] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3698.84.15/UICollectionView.m:5908
2018-12-05 12:51:16.949957-0800 SweatNetOffline[71327:19904799] [error] fault: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to delete item 1 from section 0 which only contains 1 items before the update with userInfo (null)
```

Why is attempting here to delete item 1... I don't really understand this error message. I believe it should just be inserting an item at the new index path as a new Tag "Two" has been created in the database. What is going on here?

Comment: Do you have the proper inverse relationships set up in your model?  If so, you should either add the tag to the post or add the post to the tag, but not both.

Comment: @Paulw11 The Tag entity has a relationship called posts with destination Post and Inverse "tags". The Post entity has a relationship called tags with destination Tag and inverse "posts". I read this is how you setup a many to many relationship though the inverses are a little confusing. How do I know whether to add the tag to the post or the post to the tag? In this instance I am creating a post with those tags so I assume only tag to the post....

Comment: It doesn’t matter which way you do it, but only do one. I would set the tags on the new Post

Comment: Either way doesn't remove the error. The behavior suggests that maybe its overwriting the original tag in the database with a new name ("Two"). I have realized that if I use "Two" instead of "One", "Two" for the second post, this issue does not arise...

Comment: I was mistaken. Deleting the database and making that change does fix this issue

Comment: Are you sure?  I created a test application and was able to duplicate your error and my code didn't update both objects explicitly; see my answer

Comment: With that change and your suggestion about the indexPath vs newIndexPath, it seems to be working (after deleting the database and starting again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by using `newIndexPath` instead of `indexPath` in the `.update` case.

When you assign an existing tag to a post, that `Tag` object is updated.  This causes a `.updated` event to be posted to the `NSFetchResultsControllerDelegate`.

In the delegate method `newIndexPath` represents the index path of the object *after* inserts have been processed, while `indexPath` represents the index path of the object *before* insertions.

The documentation for [`performBatchUpdates:completion`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618045-performbatchupdates) states:

> Deletes are processed before inserts in batch operations. This means the indexes for the deletions are processed relative to the indexes of the collection view’s state before the batch operation, and the indexes for the insertions are processed relative to the indexes of the state after all the deletions in the batch operation.

As insertions are performed last, when you attempt to reload `newIndexPath` you get the exception, as you are attempting to reload an element that hasn't yet been inserted.

Changing your code to refer to `indexPath` in this case resolves your problem.

```
 case .update:
     blockOperations.append(
         BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
             if let this = self {
                 this.latestTagsCollectionView!.reloadItems(at: [indexPath!])
             }
         })
     )
```

Also, you only need to update the `Post` *or* the `Tag`; as there are inverse references in place, Core Data will take care of updating the other objects

Comment: Do you mean indexPath! instead of IndexPath! ? This issue is fixed with that, this change, and your suggestion about only adding the tag to the post, and not the post to the tag.